# How to do Unit Testing + code-coverage with file upload in Laravel 5.2

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, laravel-5

I want to do some unit testing with file upload on Laravel 5.2.

Here is how I do it refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396075/1040934):

```
/** app/Http/routes.php **/
Route::post('upload', function() {
    $fileExists = false;

    if ($_FILES['images']) {
        $fileExists = true;
    }

    return ['result' => $fileExists];
});

/** tests/ExampleTest.php **/
public function testUploadFile()
{
    $file = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
        base_path() . '/tests/files/profile.png', 'profile.png');

        $response = $this->call('POST', 'upload', 
            [
               'firstname' => 'firstname', 
               'lastname'  => 'lastname', 
               'promotion' => '2016', 
               'isCoop' => 1
            ], 
            [
               'images' => [$file]
            ]
        );
}
```

The result of phpunit is:
[image: phpunit result]

But, when I check the code coverage result, the line inside the if statement on routes.php file is not executed as shown below.

[image: Code coverage result]

It seems the uploaded file is not inserted into `$_FILES` variable, so it detected as empty.

Any idea how to fix it..? Thanks.

***Notes: I used Larave for create an API Service, so I did not used form to upload the file***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 Mocked file upload unit test fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196500/laravel-5-2-mocked-file-upload-unit-test-fails)

Answer (score 1):

After laravel 5.2.15 this is happening because you are using

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
```

instead of

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile
```

And file is never sent to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write:

```
[
    'images' => $file
]
```

Instead of

```
[
    'images' => [$file]
]
```

Also, you should use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instead of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile after 5.2.15 see [Laravel 5.2 Mocked file upload unit test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196500/laravel-5-2-mocked-file-upload-unit-test-fails)